# Input output struct function error in c

Tags: c, function, struct

This code should read information of books and then print the information, but I have an error in the function, `void in_book(struct books z)`, `void out_book(struct books z)`

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct books{
int id;
float price;
char title[15];
char description[140];
};

void in_book(struct books z){
printf("Enter the title\n");
gets(z.title);
printf("Enter the description\n");
gets(z.description);
printf("Enter the id\n");
scanf("%d",&z.id);
printf("Enter the price\n");
scanf("%f",&z.price);
}

void out_book(struct books z){
printf("Title       : %s\n",z.title);
printf("Description : %s\n",z.description);
printf("Id          : %d\n",z.id);
printf("Price       : %.1f\n",z.price);
}

void main(){
struct books b1;
in_book(b1);
out_book(b1);
}
```

this is the output

> Enter the title 
>     book 
>     Enter the description 
>     a book 
>  
>     Enter the id 
>  
>     1234 
>     Enter the price 
>     55 
>     Title       : 
>     Description : 
>     Id          : 0
>     Price       : 0.0

Comment: There is currently only one book you should read: A good and modern C textbook.

Comment: Never, never, ***never*** use `gets`, It has been removed from the C-standard because it is horribly unsafe with buffer overrun exploits. Instead used `fgets`, e.g. `fgets(z.title; sizeof z.title, stdin);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the value of each field of the struct in the *Call-by-value* way, that means that the changes are only visible in the functions each. If you want to set the values so that the struct in the main function holds all changes, you'll need a pointer to your struct:

```
struct books *b1 = malloc(sizeof(struct books));
```

And then pass the pointer around:

```
in_book(b1);
out_book(b1);
```

Modify the functions as follows:

```
void in_book(struct books *z){
    printf("Enter the title\n");
    gets(z->title);
    printf("Enter the description\n");
    gets(z->description);
    printf("Enter the id\n");
    scanf("%d",&z->id);
    printf("Enter the price\n");
    scanf("%f",&z->price);
}

void out_book(struct books *z){
    printf("Title       : %s\n",z->title);
    printf("Description : %s\n",z->description);
    printf("Id          : %d\n",z->id);
    printf("Price       : %.1f\n",z->price);
}
```

**EDIT:**

Also you should look up the topics "**Call-by-value**" as well as "**Call-by-reference**".

Comment: C does not support call-by-reference. A pointer is a first-class type.

Comment: Sorry I recalled that from other laguages like C++. It's true that C doesn't know Call-by-reference, but pointer as arguments have the same behaviour as what is known as Call-by-reference .

Comment: Do not use `gets`.

Answer (score -1):

you need create menmory

```
struct books *b1 = malloc(sizeof(struct books))
```